# how to print the checklist array value

Tags: php, html

I want to print the checklist array value, here checklist is dynamically created for each row of Food table. How I can do that ? If I click submit no value is submitted I guess so, How to use submit button? In fact where to use ..plz help me

```
<?php // File: anyco.php
    require('anyco_ui.inc.php');
    // Create a database connection
    $conn = oci_connect('system','123','localhost/orcl');
    ui_print_header('FoodItemList');

    //session_start();
    //$cid=$_SESSION['cid'];
    //do_query($conn, 'SELECT   Fooditem_ID,Food_item_name,price,day_available,time_available,discount_percentage,start_date,deadline FROM Food_Item');
    ui_print_footer(date('Y-m-d H:i:s'));

    function do_query($conn, $query)
    {
            $stid = oci_parse($conn, $query);
            $r = oci_execute($stid,OCI_DEFAULT);
            print '<table border="1">';
            print '<tr>';
            print '<td>Food_ID<td>Food_Name<td>Price(tk)<td>Dvailable_day<td>Avaliable_time<td>Discount<td>Dis_start date<td>Dis_finish date<td>selected item<td>quanity';
            while ($row = oci_fetch_array($stid, OCI_ASSOC+OCI_RETURN_NULLS)) 
            {
                print '<tr>';
                $num=1;
                $val="";
                foreach ($row as $item) 
                {                  
                    if($num==1)
                    { 
                       $val = $item;
                       $num=2;
                    }

                    print '<td>'.($item!== null ? htmlentities($item) : '&nbsp;').'</td>';

                }
                //echo$val;
                echo '<td><input type="checkbox" name = "invite[]" value="$val>" </td>';
                echo '<td><input type="number" name = "name[]" ></td>';
                print '</tr>';
           }

       print '</table>';
    }
    if(isset($_POST['submit']))
    {
      if (is_array($_POST['invite']))
      {
         foreach($_POST['invite'] as $key=>$name)
         {
          echo $key, '=>', $name,'<br/>';
          //Here $key is the array index and $name is the value of the checkbox
         }
     }


    }   


?>
<html>
<style>
body
{
background:orange;
}
</style>
<body text="green">
<br><br>
<form method="post">
<?php do_query($conn, 'SELECT Fooditem_ID,Food_item_name,price,day_available,time_available,discount_percentage,start_date,deadline FROM Food_Item'); ?>

<input type ="submit" value="submit" name="submit"><br><br>


</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you r sumbit buttom have missing the name property

Answer (score 0):

Your form doesn't have any inputs inside it because you are calling your function way before you print out the form tags.

This line needs to move to within the form:

```
do_query($conn, 'SELECT Fooditem_ID,Food_item_name,price,day_available,time_available,discount_percentage,start_date,deadline FROM Food_Item');
```

So that the code looks like this, and the whole table with its inputs is printed *inside* the form tags. I also added a name for the submit button:

```
<form method="post">

<?php do_query($conn, 'SELECT Fooditem_ID,Food_item_name,price,day_available,time_available,discount_percentage,start_date,deadline FROM Food_Item'); ?>

<input type ="submit" value="submit" name="submit"><br><br>

</form>
```

Finally, when you echo values into your inputs, there are two syntax errors in this line:

```
echo '<td><input type="checkbox" name = "invite[]" value="$val>" </td>';
```

You can echo a variable into a string in several ways - here are two. 1) if the variable is between single quotes, PHP will automatically convert the variable to its value. In this case, it's double quotes, so no go. 2) You start your echo command with single quotes, so you can break out of the string with a single quote, concatenate the variable with a period, and then break back in to the string with another single quote, like this:

```
echo '<td><input type="checkbox" name = "invite[]" value="' . $val . '"> </td>';
```

Comment: if i use the following line for printing the values of the array it is like this
0=>$val>
1=>$val>



 but i saved the fooditem id in the checkbox value as $val ..so why the values of fooditemid is not printing ?

  

     echo '<td><input type="checkbox" name = "invite[]" value="$val"></td>';


here $val contains the fooditemidof my Food-Item table ;
i want to use this value ..but i cant use them ..whats the way?